# complex ajax query using parse api

Tags: javascript, python, api, parse-platform

Im dealing with parse.com's apis. I want to make complex queries in my javascript function.

I couldnt manage to equivalant params section below code for ajax get request. Any help appriciated.

For example, to retrieve scores between 1000 and 3000, they gave example in python,

```
import json,httplib,urllib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
params = urllib.urlencode({"where":json.dumps({
       "score": {
         "$gte": 1000,
         "$lte": 3000
       }
     })})
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/GameScore?%s' % params, '', {
       "X-Parse-Application-Id": "pcHvGniu2bbGggMofkcVKQUK91g5V3U5g4ZGWifK",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "5pI5vb7dNu8mRY6yPFTOtpIdpUHeqv5gMChFaQxK"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
print result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in javascript can be even shorter:

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'pcHvGniu2bbGggMofkcVKQUK91g5V3U5g4ZGWifK');
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", '5pI5vb7dNu8mRY6yPFTOtpIdpUHeqv5gMChFaQxK');
        },
        url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore",
        data: "where=" + escape(JSON.stringify({"score": {"$gte": 1000, "$lte": 3000 }})),
        processData: false,
        success: function(msg) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(msg));
        }
});
```

JQuery will append data to url as query string, the final request url will be:

```
https://api.parse.com//1/classes/GameScore?where=%7B%22score%22%3A%7B%22%24gte%22%3A1000%2C%22%24lte%22%3A3000%7D%7D
```

And of course it's OK to construct the url by ourselves:

```
var url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore?where=" + escape(JSON.stringify({"score": {"$gte": 1000, "$lte": 3000 }}))
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id", 'pcHvGniu2bbGggMofkcVKQUK91g5V3U5g4ZGWifK');
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", '5pI5vb7dNu8mRY6yPFTOtpIdpUHeqv5gMChFaQxK');
    },
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(msg));
    }
```

});

The request URL is the same as the previous one.

Comment: thank you Daniel,  i  put end of url  like; url + '"?where=" + escape(JSON.stringify(...' and it works thank you again. If you edit your answer i appreciate

Comment: Sorry for that, I added an extra slash in the URL: "https://api.parse.com//1/classes/GameScore", if you encountered some problem, it may be caused by it. And thanks for your suggestion, I added more explanation on request URL construction.